# Use two font styles with Lettrine

Tags: lettrine

I want to use two style of fonts to drop the first character.  First style GoudyInfamily color violet, and for 3 lines, for first paragraph in a chapter.  Some of the remainder paragraphs in the chapter will have a dropped number, in color blue, 2 lines height, and the same default font family of the paragraph (I use the book class)  I use TexStudio with pdftext.

I am able to use only one font style with

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\color{VioletRed4}\GoudyInfamily{}}
\LettrineTextFont{\itshape}
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}
```

Comment: why can't you repeat those three lines with the other setting before each paragraph that needs it? (Also it would be helpful if you provided a test document that showed the problem)

Comment: Did you try defining an own macro for lettrines, that first changes the specifications?